# Maven dependency management: Exclusion without version

Tags: maven

I would like to use a Spring Boot library:

```
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<parent>
    <artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've got other, similar projects and I'd like to manage the version of Spring in one place:

```
<artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

However, I don't want Spring's logging libraries.  I've got my own.

```
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<parent>
    <artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

That works.

But I don't want to have to repeat the exclusion every time I use the dependency:

```
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<parent>
    <artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
    ...
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That doesn't work.

```
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar is missing.
```

Of course, I can specify just hard-code the same version as is used in spring-boot-dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But now I have to manage two versions (which happen be the same in this case).

Is there a way for me to inherit/import dependencies and manage exclusions *without* having to repeat versioning information?

Comment: Use two variables for spring-boot-dependencies version and spring-boot-starter-data-pa version, initially assign the second with the first

Comment: I know.  But it just seems weird that I have to do that.  Surely it already knows the version!? (via the parent)  It seems contrary to the rest over Maven behaviour.  I.e. Properties are inherited and potentially overridden.

Comment: dependencyManagement tag is built to hold all GAV data ... what you propose would be a nice to have feature