# Maven dependencyManagement: inherit dependency version from parent

Tags: maven, maven-3

I want my dependency in `dependencyManagement` block to inherit a version from `spring-boot-parent`'s `dependencyManagement` block, but add exclusion to it, so that I don't need to specify that exclusion in each of child modules.

My parent pom inherits from spring-boot-parent:

```
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>???</version>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
  </dependencyManagement>
```

child pom inherits `my-parent`:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I tried several approaches:

- When I replace `???` with `${parent.version}`, in child module this version is resolved to be `my-parent`'s version: `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`, which is incorrect.
- When I replace `???` with `${parent.parent.version}`, maven breaks, as it doesn't support such properties
- I can fix `???` to be `2.0.1.RELEASE` and this will work fine, but if I update the version of spring boot, I have to remember to update the version of this dependency also, which is non-intuitive
- I cannot extract `2.0.1.RELEASE` as a property in `my-parent` and use that property as parent version, as maven does not support that.
- I could've used property with value `2.0.1.RELEASE` inherited from `spring-boot-parent` pom, but there is none such property, as far as I can see.

Is there a nice way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Solution 5 is out: see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5014

Comment: Have you simply tried to remove the version at all in dependencyManagement block?

Comment: @khmarbaise, yes, maven complains that version is missing

Comment: I still see this problem with mvn 3.6.0/3.6.1

Comment: Duplicate (no solution): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330834/maven-dependency-management-exclusion-without-version

Answer (score 2):

See [Possible to have the parent version as Property to give to the children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359934/possible-to-have-the-parent-version-as-property-to-give-to-the-children) - the version used to declare your  parent can't be repurposed in a way that says "make this reference fixed to mean its interpretation at this point in the graph". Strings are strings and placeholders are placeholders; there's no built-in facility to have some kind of in-between thing. If the parent uses a property to define a dependency version you can reference that property; if it uses a fixed string (as in your case) then you'll need to repeat *something* in order to define an exclusion. As referenced in the linked question, a common way is something like this:

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
  <properties>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        ...
```

You still have to repeat the value in two fields -- so you have to make very sure that you always keep those in sync ([parent](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-parent-mojo.html) version and [property](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html)).

However, the increasingly-popular way to manage this is to declare those versions in a BOM (a "bill-of-materials" pom with the specific purpose of keeping a set of components aligned). Then the `dependencyManagement` stuff can be imported instead of inherited. Spring Boot has been doing this for a while now; in fact the parent in your example doesn't actually declare the dependencies itself, they come from a different artifact. So instead of inheriting from the parent, you could do something like this (I *might* have the sequence of these backwards -- I can't remember whether first or last wins):

```
  <properties>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        ...
```

... now, if there are other reasons (beyond just dep mgmt) you wanted to inherit from `spring-boot-starter-parent` then this won't really help your problem; you'll still need to duplicate. But I suspect that as your project matures you'll want to have a parent of your own devising anyway.